# How to write diffrent code for ios and android in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a xamarin.forms project. Suppose I have a button, and I want this button to call different platforms' APIs (third-party ios / android skd) on different platforms.

1. How to import jar for xamarin.android/ios sdk for xamarin.ios?
2. Assuming this button is in a page of xamarin.forms, how do I bind different events for different platforms so that it can call different APIs on different platforms?

Project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: how to override the button event in xamarin.android/xamarin.ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you must implement dependency service

Pseudo code example

In shared code create public interface

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

In specific platform code create dependency service

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyServiceIOS))]

namespace MyNamespace.iOS
{
    public class MyServiceIOS : IService
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are right, It is the answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 2):

1. Xamarin has documentation about binding native libraries. You can find android [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) and ios [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive).
2. You can do different things in button click event for different platforms with using [Xamarin.Forms Device Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device).

   ```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
           {
               case Device.iOS:
                  //Do iOS thing
                   break;
               case Device.Android:
                   //Do Android thing
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
       }
   ```

3.If you want to work with different platform api then you can use Dependency Service just like Adlorem's answer. Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Comment: This won't work if you are using third party library for each platform.

Comment: Thanks,But my needs are more complicated, Adlorem is right, I need dependency service , just find this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction